# Google Maps API v3 draw arrow past end of Polyline?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm currently adding an arrow like this:

```
var arrowSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
    scale: 4
};

var line_options = {
    path: path,
    geodesic: true,
    clickable: false,
    strokeColor: color,
    strokeOpacity: .7,
    strokeWeight: stroke,
    icons: [{
        icon:arrowSymbol,
        offset:'100%'
    }]
}
```

The problem is that the stroke weight on my line is rather large. The tip of the arrow is right at the end of the line, and the line bulges out past the arrow's tip and looks weird. What I need is for the base of the arrow to be at the end of the line.

Comment: did you try changing the anchor of the icon?  Or making a custom SVG symbol?

Comment: Changing the anchor was what I needed. Thank you. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the anchor of the icon.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol

> anchor | Point | The position of the symbol relative to the marker or polyline. The coordinates of the symbol's path are translated left and up by the anchor's x and y coordinates respectively. By default, a symbol is anchored at (0, 0). The position is expressed in the same coordinate system as the symbol's path.